# how to fix saved image with Zero byte android java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an Image in web server and load it to Image View using Picasso perfectly then  save it to a folder in internal storage memory every thing is OK but the problem is the saved image size is 0 byte 
here is my code

```
File newDir=new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),"km");


    if (!newDir.exists()) {
        if (!newDir.mkdirs()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "can not create directory", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }

    Picasso.with(this).load("http://192.168.1.101/cima/1.jpg").into(img);

     File file = new File(new File("/storage/sdcard0/Download/km/"), "1.jpg");
    img.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bmap = img.getDrawingCache();

    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
    }

    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

any help for this issue ??

Answer (score 0):

Try to below code

```
Picasso.with(getActivity())
                .load(url)
                .into(new Target() {
                          @Override
                          public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                              try {
                                  String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                                  File myDir = new File(root + "/yourDirectory");

                                  if (!myDir.exists()) {
                                      myDir.mkdirs();
                                  }

                                  String name = new Date().toString() + ".jpg";
                                  myDir = new File(myDir, name);
                                  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(myDir);
                                  bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);

                                  out.flush();
                                  out.close();
                              } catch(Exception e){
                                  // some action
                              }
                          }

                          @Override
                          public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
                          }

                          @Override
                          public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                          }
                      }
                );
```

Comment: i got the same issue